# Remove last character from result

Tags: php

How can I remove the last character (,) of my output.

I tried several things, but none of them worked for me.
This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT t_id, t_time, t_value FROM templogger";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $string = "[".$row["t_time"].", ".$row["t_value"]."],";
      $trim = substr($string, 0, -1);
```

echo $trim;

```
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to print time and value just like a JSON array?

Comment: Don't echo it out immediately, build a larger string, remove the trailing comma by doing `substr($string, 0, -1)` and then echo it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your output, then echo it out once after removing the final comma.

```
$final = "";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $final .= "[".$row["t_time"].", ".$row["t_value"]."],";
}
$final = substr($final, 0, -1);
echo $final;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't output it in the first place.

Bruteforce:

```
$first = true;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  if( !$first ) { echo ','; }
  echo "[".$row["t_time"].", ".$row["t_value"]."]";
}
```

Implode:

```
$foo = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $foo[] = "[".$row["t_time"].", ".$row["t_value"]."]";
}
echo implode(',', $foo);
```

But if you're just trying to output JSON like @rotvulpix suggested then you shouldn't be trying to manually format it in the first place:

```
$foo = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $foo[] = [ $row["t_time"], $row["t_value"] ];
}
echo json_encode($foo);
```

Comment: Bit of a n00b here, don't know anything about JSON, I am writing a microtime into a database. I like to extract the date/time and a value to add it into FLOT

Comment: Personally a big fan of using implode(). Most elegant solution to this, waiting with output until you're done is a good approach at any rate. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$total     = $result->num_rows;
$counter   = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '['.$row['t_time'].', '.$row['t_value'].']';
    if (++$counter !== $total) {
        echo ',';
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant solution, but this should do the trick.

Replace:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "[".$row["t_time"].", ".$row["t_value"]."],";
}
```

With:

```
$z=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row_array[$z] = "[".$row["t_time"].", ".$row["t_value"]."]";
    $z++;
}

$z=0;
while($z < count($row_array)) {
    if($z == count($row_array)-1) {
        echo $row_array[$z];
    } else {
        echo $row_array[$z].',';    
    }
    $z++;
}
```